# Stable sort a huge file

Tags: linux, sorting, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I want to sort a huge file on a column. The sort should be stable. Currently, I am using unix sort(with -s option). But it is very slow. Are there well known routines to do this in hdfs?

I tried PIG's orderby but that is not stable.

Comment: How big is the file (gigabytes, terabytes, petabytes)? Show some of its lines (or row). How slow is running `sort -s` on it (hours, days?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the file into chunks (you might be able to do that on the command line, but it depends on the data; you might need a program to do that). The chunk size is up to you (a few megabytes is fine; make sure unix sort is fast with one chunk).

Then sort each chunk using unix sort (`sort -s -k...`). If you have multiple machines, you can do that in parallel.

Then merge all sorted chunks using unix sort (`sort -m -k...`). This should be stable as well if you specify the file list in the right order. If it is not (I didn't test that and didn't find any info, but most likely it is stable), then you might need to write your own merge program, which shouldn't be very complicated.

If you have too many chunks to merge efficiently, you could merge chunks 1..10 together to chunk a, then merge chunks 11..20 to chunk b (again you can do that on multiple machines in parallel), and finally merge chunks a..z. But I doubt this is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) program using [std::stable_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/)

If the file is huge so is larger than the available RAM, you may consider sorting chunks and merging them.